# Installing and configuring LDAP(AD LDS) on windows 7

Tags: windows

How to install Ldap on windows7 and to configure it??

Did some googling..cant find any exact article..

any suggestions??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On page: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=a45059af-47a8-4c96-afe3-93dab7b5b658 you can find installation for AD LDS. It's actually some kind of update for Win7. When your installation is done, to install AD LDS you have installation wizard in Control Panel/Administrative tool. Also, in same window you have ADSI Edit to get approach to AD LDS instances.

Comment: That is, assuming he wants Microsoft's Active Directory-like version of LDAP... Otherwise, I might suggest an Open Source LDAP server like Apache Directory Server (installation how-to at http://directory.apache.org/apacheds/1.5/13-installing-and-starting-the-server.html).

Comment: @ewall - this question is tagged "windows" by the OP. I wouldnt think he would want an Apache server.

Comment: @Devtron -- Aye, but there is a Windows version of ADS on the linked page. I wouldn't recommend AD LDS for anyone who needs pure LDAP, but since the OP didn't specify.

Comment: @ewall, "I wouldn't recommend AD LDS for anyone who needs pure LDAP" why?

Comment: @MikeChaliy, it's only opinion I suppose, I find many of Microsoft's LDAP tools to be rather different than the majority of *NIX-based directory services, and it's frustrating that it needs to be patched pretty much every month. But it does work, and is stable, so it's not all bad :)